# Web page can load in a desktop browser but not in mobile Safari nor a UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview

Does anybody know why this url works fine on a desktop browser (Safari) but mobile safari or UIWebView can't handle it

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/groupon/id352683833?mt=8‏

They give
WebKitErrorDomain code 101 and 102

Comment: Are you trying to send the user to view an app in the App Store from an iOS device?

Comment: I'm not, but another companies product I was looking at was, and I discovered this difference in behavior and was curious as I'm currently working with UIWebView for something different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the server (at Apple) detects that the user-agent is an iPad and probably sends a redirect to a different URL scheme (the App Store's scheme in this case).

Just tested out that url, on my iPad, with Dolphin browser, using the desktop mode (different user-agent), and it worked perfectly.

You can verify if this is the case (I bet it is anyway) by intercepting your iPad's http traffic.